# Accessing CakePHP code

Tags: html, cakephp

I have a client who has a custom app built with CakePHP. He wants me to change some photos that are displayed on the front in a slider. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to even access the back end code of the app. On his FTP server is only an index.php file that has the documentation for CakePHP. Can anyone point me in the right direction as far as even finding the code in question? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, when it comes to CakePHP it really depends. The photos could be loaded dynamically by the backend or they could be hardcoded into the templates. To find the file where this can be located varies depending on the version of CakePHP you have installed.

The frontpage could be located here:

`src/Template/Pages/home.ctp` Version 3.x

`app/View/Pages/home.ctp` Version 2.x

`app/views/pages/home.ctp` Version 1.3

This is based on what defaults could be. As noted before, the homepage template file could be anywhere.

Comment: Thank you very much! It was in app/view/pages/home.ctp. The images are hosted locally and I have access to those I just had no clue how to change the images myself. I felt pretty dumb as the client was able to change these himself and he's stated multiple times that he's a complete dummy with this stuff. Thanks again!